# Combine Json Files with a Continuing Index

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

**UPDATE**: Json File**s**:
[LINK](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5ee60d90e3841317d44a431d49ce1edb20230104101526/6445b1)

I have a multitude of Json files that have the same individual structure:

```
0:
 Title
 Location
 Price
 Net area
 Gross area
 ...

1: 
 Title
 Location
 ...

2: 
 ...
```

One Json file may run from index 0: to 56:, while another may run from 0: to 60:. I have endlessly sought to combine them with .concat, .join, and .merge but the final Json file never is what I expected. Combining 0: to 56: with 0:to 60 should give a new Json file running from 0: to 118 (index). But at best I get the following structure:

```
0: 
  0:
    Title
    ...
  1:
    Title
    ...
1:
  0: 
    Title
    ...
  1: 
    Title
    ...
2:
  0:
    Title
    ...
  1:
    Title
    ...
```

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb35p.png)

Here is the code I used:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('Belem_data_p1.json') as f1:
    data1=json.load(f1)
with open('Belem_data_p2.json') as f2:
    data2=json.load(f2)

df1=pd.DataFrame([data1])
df2=pd.DataFrame([data2])

MergeJson=pd.concat([df1,df2]).reset_index()
MergeJson.to_json('NewFileName.json')
print (MergeJson)
```

I need the combination of DataFrames to update the index so that my data appears as such:

```
0: 
  Title
  Location
  ...

[...]

118:
 Title
 Location
 ...
```

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVZdz.png)
I'd be so thankful for a fix, because I've been searching endlessly and couldn't find the solution!

**EDITS:**

**NIYAZ**

Link to the newly produced Json file: [LINK](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a4659e8761d2c249f0d0ca1e493888ca20230104095203/5c81b2)

Code ran:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('Belem_data_p1.json') as f1:
    data1=json.load(f1)
with open('Belem_data_p2.json') as f2:
    data2=json.load(f2)

df=pd.DataFrame(data=(list(data1.values())+list(data2.values())))
print((len(df)))
df.tail(10)
df.to_json('ImYourJson44.json')
```

**ZYLESTO**

New file produced: [LINK](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d05690feabb87ec8def34089592e767720230104101724/38cdd9)

Code ran:

```
import json

with open('Belem_data_p1.json') as f1:
    data1=json.load(f1)
with open('Belem_data_p2.json') as f2:
    data2=json.load(f2)

data=dict(data1)
data.update(data2)

with open('Belem_FINAL.json','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data,outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to not create a new DataFrame for each JSON file, but concatenate the data with a loop:

```
import json

# Load the data from the JSON files
with open('file1.json') as f1:
    data1 = json.load(f1)
with open('file2.json') as f2:
    data2 = json.load(f2)

# Concatenate the data
result = data1
index = len(data1)

for k in range(len(data2)):
    result[str(index)] = data2[str(k)]
    index = index + 1

# Save the combined data to a new JSON file
with open('combinedFile.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

Comment: Hello there Zylesto. I tried your suggestion. However, data1+data2 returns a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'. I tried with data1|data2 syntax instead, and the file produced is only a copy of the second json file.

Comment: Hello. This time I get the following Error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). My data type should be JSON objects, given the structure of the file.

Comment: I have tried it with the sample file you have provided and it works fine. Maybe your input file is corrupted? Have you checked whether your file is in a correct JSON format? Use e.g. an online checker for that.

Comment: Hey @Zylesto I re-opened my folder and tried again. The segment you provided does work. It produces a new file with the original structure I need. However, there are only 70 items, corresponding to the 70 items of the second file (data2). So, the operation does not add any new data somehow, it just creates a copy of the second file. I updated my original post for you to consult the file + additional files for you to run the code with two distinct Jsons.

Comment: Thank you very much for the new file, I have updated the code accordingly. It is now getting merged into a file with 134 JSONs. Let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: Hey @Zylesto. Wow, thank you so much. Now it does work. I should have mentioned that the way I initially crafted the files had a structure similar to how you fixed my merging issue :) I will upload the final answer to the question. Once again, many thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I could fix my issue thanks to the contribution of @Zylesto:

```
import json

# Load the data from the JSON files
with open('file1.json') as f1:
    data1 = json.load(f1)
with open('file2.json') as f2:
    data2 = json.load(f2)

# Concatenate the data
result = data1
index = len(data1)

for k in range(len(data2)):
    result[str(index)] = data2[str(k)]
    index = index + 1

# Save the combined data to a new JSON file
with open('combinedFile.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```